# Access any background worker created in runtime

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

**Scenario:** I have a `DataGrid` in my application in which `onclikcing` each row, the values get populated in the `texboxes` below. I'll update the values and when clicking save the process is taking more time to complete.

So i have written a backgroundworker to make the process run `asynchronously`. When each row is clikced an instance of a `backgroundworker` is created and the process is accomplished. During that update the user will select the second row of the grid and update that values. So this will create another instance and the process will run in background.

Now when both the update process is running if the user selects the first row of the grid there should be a message showing "The process is still running".

//Code:

' OnClick of the event

```
         var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
          bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
          bw.DoWork += delegate {
              SaveDetails();
          };
          bw.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate {
              MessageBox.Show("Completed");
          };
          bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

'Save method

```
 public void SaveDetails()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10;i++ )
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            MessageBox.Show("Hi");

        }
    }
```

How can i access the previously created backgroundworker instance and check the status of the process and display the messgage?

**Note:** There may be many process running simultaneously, so i should be able to access any process.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store any `BackgrounWorker` you create in a `List` to refer to them at any moment, but alternatively you can create a tasks `Queue` and store there any pending process, so you have only one `BackgroundWorker` at any time.

### Storing the BackgroundWorkers in a List

Create a `List(Of BackgroundWorker)` which can be accesed anywhere you need in your code, for example. Every time you create a new `BackgroundWorker`, add it to the `List`:

```
mylist.Add(bw)
```

You a lot of options to access the correct `backgroundworker` later on. The easiest one is to create your own class which will have an identificator (the row of the `DataGrid`, for example) and the `backgroundworker`. This way, your `list` will be of this class instead of `BackgroundWorkers`:

```
myClass.BackgroundWorkerProperty = bw
myClass.id = myId
myList.Add(myClass)
```

### Using a Queue to run the tasks

Create a `Queue` with a type which has the information to run the task. For example, the row of the `DataGrid`, if that's enought, that will be type `Integer` (the index), then add it everytime the `backgroundworker` is running:

```
myQueue.Add(myRow)
```

Everytime the `backgroundworker` finish, check the `Queue` and run the next task stored.

Comment: I thought of this idea. But couldn't make it. Can u post a sample code? In which i need to make sure that the correct instance is mapped for the row of the grid(value being updated).

Comment: Which one? Creating a `Queue` to run all the process in order or storing all the `BackgroundWorker`s in a `List`?

Comment: Both. What are the values that should be stored in the list and a queue.?

Comment: Hope the first approach(List) will work fine for my application. Since it is a big one let me try and post if i have issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Tag` property of the `DataGridViewRow`:

```
var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
row.Tag = bw;
```

So you can access it.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using .NET 4.5** i would suggest to use Async/Await rather than Background thread to solve your problem, because its programming style is easy and efficient as given below:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Task<bool>> taskList = new List<Task<bool>>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            Task<bool> task = Task.Run(() => SaveDetails());
            MessageBox.Show(task.Id + " started.");
            taskList.Add(task);
            var isSuccess = await task;
        }
        public bool SaveDetails()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                //MessageBox.Show("Finishing.");                
            }
            return true;
        }       

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            foreach (var task in taskList)
            {                
                if (task.IsCompleted == true)
                    MessageBox.Show(task.Id + " Completed.");
            }        
        }
    }
```

i have created a second button click event to access and display all currently completed tasks.
Also, please make a note that you can use `task.Id` as the row identifier of your grid row.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

well, that's rather easy. put the `BackgroundWorker` as a member in your form and then you can access it from everywhere:

```
BackgroundWorker bg;

public Form1()
{
    bg = new BackgroundWorker();
}


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
         if(bg.IsBusy)
         {
             // show the message
         }
         else
         {
              bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
              bw.DoWork += delegate {
                 SaveDetails();
              };
              bw.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate {
                 MessageBox.Show("Completed");
              };
              bw.RunWorkerAsync();
         }
}
```

Comment: How can i know that for which row the particluar background is running? I need to access like for the first updation this instance of the background is running and for the second this instance and on.....

Comment: @SanthoshKumar i would have created a Dictionary, from Point to BackgroundWorker. do you need an example?